# Arc length and area under curve

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, arc-length

Hey guys I'm having trouble proving the area under the curve is the same as the arc length the question is:

> $f(x)= \frac{1}{4}e^x+e^{-x}$ , prove that's the arc length on any interval has the same value as area under the curve.

For the arc length I got $\frac{1}{4}(e^x-4e^{-x})+C$. But I didn't get that for the area under the curve. Please help thank you !!

Comment: For the area under the curve....you just integrate the e-powers.....Give that a try first.

Comment: I did and I just got 1/4(e^x)-e^-x

Comment: Well, take a look at Deepak's suggestion.Once you have done your derivative work, it really boils done to an equation...

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Let $\displaystyle y = f(x)$

Arc length between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is given by $\displaystyle \int_{X_1}^{X_2} \sqrt{1 + (y')^2}dx$

Area under the curve between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is given by $\displaystyle \int_{X_1}^{X_2} ydx$

So all you need to do is prove that $\displaystyle \sqrt{1 + (y')^2} = y$ holds identically true.

Can you show that $\displaystyle {1 + (y')^2} = y^2$ for all $x$?